Why can photon be treated like gas?
In Cosmology, especially when studying Cosmic Dynamic, sometime we will treat photons as gas to calculate its pressure, but according to my understanding, photon and gas are nothing alike. Why can photons be treated  like gas even though they are not the same thing? In calculations related to white dwarfs, we also assume that electrons are like gas as well, are these two gas fundamentally the same thing or they have a difference?

The essence of a gas is that the interactions are negligible. Ideal gas. Photons interact with each other so little that this is phenomenal. Electrons might interact with each other very little if the fermion degeneracy freezes most of that out. So then we call those systems as gases. If they do interact more, then we call them liquids.

So what you are saying is gas is a bunch of particles that rarely interact with each other, am I correct in this way?

@naturallyInconsistent looks like an answer to me

@Polaris5744 you would have to tag me so that I would even know that you are asking me a question. The answer is yes.

@naturallyInconsistent Thank you for the response!

So, usually, any group of particles which have very weak interaction between them can be compared to an ideal gas. If the interaction is slightly more, then it is compared to a liquid and if the inter particle forces are very strong that the particle's kinetic energy becomes less than the interaction-based potential energy, then it's compared to a solid. They might be different phases of matter but this nomenclature is made strictly on the basis of their interparticle interaction strength. For examples, you can search Fermi gas, Electron liquid, Wigner Solid etc.
Photons do interact with each other, but at sufficiently high energies of >GeVs. But at lower energies, photon-photon scattering can be considered completely elastic and as such, photons behave like gas particles. That is why photons are referred to as photon gas. And in general, they follow Bose-Einstein statistics, hence they are also called Bose gas.

Symmetries, said the space must be homogenous and isotropic, on large scales determine the form of their energy-momentum tensors.
By Cosmos principle, $T_{00}$, $T_{0i}$ and $T_{ij}$ are maximally form-invariant, that is to say the Lie derivative of them is 0 respect to all killing vector of space. Apply a theorem to this case one can show that $T_{00}=\rho(t)$, $\rho(t)$ is a function of t (comoving time), $T_{0i}=0$ and $T_{ij}=p(t)g_{ij}$ where $p(t)$ a function of t and $g_{ij}$ the croodinate components of metric. (The statement and proof of this Theorem is given by Weinberg Ch. 13)
Further more,
$T_{\mu\nu}=(p+\rho)u_\nu u_\mu+pg_{\mu \nu}$
where $u^0=1,u^i=0$
Such an energy-momentum tensor has the form of an ideal fluid. But this does not mean that these contents are ideal fluids or gases. Note that the symmetry we rely on to get this energy-momentum tensor is large-scale, and we neglect interactions in an average sense. This does not determine the microscopic properties of these contents.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
